# Negating quantifiers with brackets

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

My book and my teacher both said that these two statements are **different**:

1) $∀x∈A,∃y∈B, F(x, y)⇒G(x)$

2) $∀x∈A,(∃y∈B, F(x, y))⇒G(x)$

How can just adding an extra parenthesis make the statement different?
I am not quite sure I understand. 
If they are different, how are there negation different?
Would the negation be as follows:

1) $∀x∈A,∃y∈B, F(x, y) ∧ ¬ G(x)$

2) $∀x∈A,(∀y∈B, ¬ F(x, y)) ∧ ¬ G(x)$

---

SIDE NOTE:
I tried taking contrapositives, but ended up with the same expression for both. So how and why are they diffrent?
$¬ G(x) ⇒ ∃x∈A,∀y∈B, ¬ F(x, y) $

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How can just adding an extra parenthesis make the statement different?

Because adding parentheses changes the *scope* of quantifiers.

Thus, the two formulas are **not** equivalent, provided that we read 1) as: $∀x \ [∃y \ (F(x,y) \to G(x))]$.

See [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication):

> $(\exists x\phi )\rightarrow \psi$  is equivalent to $\forall x(\phi \rightarrow \psi )$.

Formula 2) is $∀x \ [(∃y \ F(x,y)) \to G(x)]$, where the scope of the existential quantifier is restricted to sub-formula $F(x,y)$.

Thus, according to the equivalence above, 2) is equivalent to: $∀x \ [∀y \ (F(x,y) \to G(x))]$.

---

An easy check: formula 2) is equivalent to: $∀x \ [\lnot (∃y \ F(x,y)) \lor G(x)]$, i.e. to: $∀x \ [(∀y \lnot F(x,y)) \lor G(x)]$.

In general, the universal quantifier does not "distribute" over $\lor$ but, due to the fact that $y$ does not occur in $G(x)$, we can move it to get: $∀x \ [∀y \ ( \lnot F(x,y) \lor G(x))]$.

---

---

Maybe your perplexities are due to the (not so good) practice of mixing commas and parentheses to identify the *scope* of quantifiers.

Formula 1): $∀x∈A,∃y∈B,F(x,y)⇒G(x)$ is $∀x∈A \ [∃y∈B \ (F(x,y)⇒G(x))]$ where the scope of the existential quantifier is the sub-formula $F(x,y)⇒G(x)$.

Formula 2): $∀x∈A,(∃y∈B,F(x,y))⇒G(x)$, instead, is $∀x∈A \ [∃y∈B \ (F(x,y)) ⇒G(x)]$ where the scope of the existential quantifier is only the sub-formula $F(x,y)$.

Comment: Does that mean #2 is equavilent to $∀x∈A,∀y∈B, F(x, y) ⇒ G(x)$

Comment: @AvaSoyet - Yes; this is what is written above.

Comment: Doesn't (∃xϕ)→ψ is equivalent to ∀x(ϕ→ψ) work ONLY because x ≠ ϕ. In this case, don't we have someting like (∃x P(x))→ ψ instead of (∃x P(ϕ) )→ψ